# Messed with Preprocessor Macro - Now iOS app won't build for device -- Cocoapods?

Tags: ios, xcode, build-process, cocoapods

I've encountered an issue where, after I added a preprocessor macro to my project, I can no longer build for device. Though the simulator works fine, building for the device produces lots and lots of compilation errors in several of my Cocoapod dependencies.

My logs for the build failures look like this:

```
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/MyUsername/Mobile/MyApp/Pods/Pods-MBProgressHUD-prefix.pch:2:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode51-Beta4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:14:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode51-Beta4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIActivityViewController.h:9:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode51-Beta4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIViewController.h:10:
/Applications/Xcode51-Beta4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:351:1: error: unexpected '@' in program
```

Another pod that failed gives me this:

```
/Users/MyUsername/Mobile/MyApp/Pods/Pods-MBProgressHUD-prefix.pch:2:9: fatal error: could not build module 'UIKit'
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Anyone know what could be going on?

Thanks!

Comment: It would help to know what preprocessor macro you added.

Comment: Well that is what is confusing me -- I at first added RELEASE=1, but then got an error, and so I reverted all changes to the project file. The issue, however, did not resolve

Comment: @SeanDanzeiser Not `-DRELEASE=1`?

Comment: sorry, I've never encountered this before and I don't know whats going on...

Comment: So can't you revert changes using that instead?

Comment: yes I did that but the problem remains -- this is why I am confused -- because the project file appears to be no different then it was before the issue began occuring